# Webpack 4 - multiple entries - multiple instances per entry

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am creating library on `window`. I need to use multiple entries, but the problem is when I want to import an instance of one class, that instance is created for every entry.

Second problem is when I am creating that library, there is only `entryA` on `window`, but `entryB` is missing.

I have created git repo with this problem.

https://github.com/vavdav/Webpack-Multiple-Entries

thank you for help